# SQL max value per group ignoring less valued rows with differing values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would need a max value per group so that result set ignores lesser valued rows; even if they have different values. Here is the example:

[image: Current result and desired result]

I'm attempting to maximize the person_id (same person has many person_ids) for every person, team and division and show only that row. Here is the simple sql that I tried.

```
SELECT max(person_id) as person_id, person_name, division_name, team_name
from organization_table
group by
person_name, 
division_name, 
team_name
```

My question is, how would I query this dataset so that SQL would return only the row with max personid for each person regardless differing team and division values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your records a rank, based on the highest person_id (`order by person_id desc`) per (`partition by`) person_name first by using a CTE and then selecting only the highest ranked record:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_name ORDER BY person_id DESC) AS RANK
  FROM organization_table
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RANK = 1;
```